# Is ∅ ⊈ { ∅, 1, 2 } False?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is this `∅ ⊈ { ∅, 1, 2 }` true or false ?

Also, I am confuse since this `{ ∅, 1, 2 }` has already contain a `∅`, does it still contain another `∅` meaning like : `{ ∅, ∅, 1, 2 }` ?

Is `∅ ∈ { ∅, 1, 2 }` true ? & `{∅} ∈ { ∅, 1, 2 }` false ?

Comment: It is trivially false since empty set is the subset of any set. This comes from the fact that empty set does not contain any element.

Comment: Don't confuse $\in$ with $\subseteq$.

Comment: $\emptyset \subset A $ is *always* true no matter *what* set $A $ is.

Answer (score 2):

$$\oslash\subset\{\oslash,1,2\}$$ and $$\oslash\in\{\oslash,1,2\}.$$
Also, $$\{\oslash\}\subset\{\oslash,1,2\}.$$

Comment: Sorry, why is {⊘} ⊂ {⊘,1,2} ?

Comment: Because it's an element of the set. Don't you write $$ \{1\} \subset \{1, 2, 3\} $$??

Comment: @J.S Because $\oslash\in\{\oslash,1,2\}.$

Answer (score 0):

No, not like that. Since null set is subset of all sets, the question in your title is valid. At least I think so.

Answer (score 0):

$\neg (A\subset B)$  iff  there exists a member of $A$ that is not a member of $B$.

Consider the case $A=\phi.$

Since $\phi$ has no members,  there cannot exist a  member of $\phi$ that fails to belong to  $B$. Therefore  $\neg (\neg (\phi\subset B))$, equivalently $\phi\subset B.$  For $any $ $B$.